# Where do I find the most up to date SQL 2005 native client driver

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to install a sql native client driver on a workstation. I do not want to install all the other tools on the workstation.

Is there an up to date installer for just the driver content.

I searched Microsoft and can find an installer from 2007 but doubt that is up to date content.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/lz6zrv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server Native Client is always included as one of the tools in the SQL Server Feature Pack:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b33d2c78-1059-4ce2-b80d-2343c099bcb4

Comment: All right I will not let the 2008 references scare me off. Looks like it will work with SQL 2005 as well. Looks to be about as up to date as can be.

Answer (score 1):

Install from SQL Server installation media and hit Windows Update

Answer (score 0):

Here

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=50b97994-8453-4998-8226-fa42ec403d17&DisplayLang=en

Comment: I am already familiar with that installer ... as mentioned in my original post. That installer does not contain the most up to date driver. I am trying to locate a similar installer with more up to date content.